# if skips straight to else C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

On the click of a button, I store the user's textbox input into an int variable "rc". After that I declared an if statement.
The problem is, that even if the user does enter a 3 or 5 or 7 or any of those options, it will just skip to else and show the MessageBox that comes with it. 
Why could this be? Here's a look at my code, ANY help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
int rc;
double centro, centro1;
int r2, c2, rc2;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Clear();
    try
    {
        rc = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
        if (rc == 3 || rc == 5 || rc == 7 || rc == 9 || rc == 11)
        {
            centro = rc / 2;
            centro1 = Math.Round(centro, 0);
            int[,] dim = new int[rc, rc];
            int v = 1, r = 0, c, x = 0;
            c = Convert.ToInt16(centro1);
            for (x = 0; x < (rc*rc); x++)
            {
                if (dim[r, c] >= 1)
                {
                    r = r2 + 2;
                    c = c2 - 1;
                    dim[r, c] = v;
                }
                else
                {
                    dim[r, c] = v;
                }

                c++;
                r--;
                v++;
                if (r < 0)
                {
                    r = rc -1;
                };

                if (c > (rc-1))
                {
                    c = 0;
                };

                r2 = r;
                c2 = c;   
            }

            string matrixString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < dim.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dim.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                     matrixString += dim[i, j].ToString();
                     matrixString += " ";
                }

                matrixString += Environment.NewLine;
            }

            this.richTextBox1.Text = matrixString;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("***Error*** 1...");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("***Error*** 2...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you declare `rc`?

Comment: Put a break point in your `if` line. What does `rc` contain? If it does not contain the expected value, what does `textBox1.Text` contain?

Comment: rest assured, c# works. If `rc` equals `3`, `5`, `7`, `9` or `11` your `if` will not branch to the `else` case.

Comment: Why do you have semi-colons after if blocks? Why do you have an else immediately following a for block?

Comment: Is this the actual code? Does it compile? As it stands, that `else` is *inside* the outer `if`, after the `for` block.

Comment: Still wrong after the edit. No closing brace for the first if. When you come here for help, please make sure you've eliminated these sorts of formatting errors in your code, so that the code you post is exactly the code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I guess one `}` is missing; either for the `for` loop or the outter `if` block.

Comment: do a try parse and see the bool value, i suspect you are getting something else too

Comment: Stackoverflow should not be a code formatting service. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is no errors, it does compile, I just didn't post the whole code to make it shorter. I apologize for that. I edited it.

Comment: @mexman3217: Then you should set a break point and have a look at `rc` in a debugger to see what's actually inside the variable and the textbox.

Comment: `... there are no errors, it does compile, ...`. That it compiles simply means there aren't any *compiler* errors. But there *is* an error in your code, because like @Jodrell mentions, C# works. The code inside the `if` block will be properly executed if the value of `rc` is `3`, `5`, `7`, `9` or `11`.

Comment: Are you sure that the message you're seeing isn't from an exception being thrown?

Comment: The if statement actually is executed. But as @BartvanNierop suggests, the message is from an IndexOutOfRange exception being thrown. You could've seen that before, if you'd actually use `(Exception ex)` after the `catch` and let the exception message being displayed with `ex.Message`.

Answer (score 3):

You're not seeing the `MessageBox` from the `else` block. Instead, you are seeing the one from your `catch` block.

See altered code below for proof, using `Console.WriteLine` instead of `MessageBox` and a `string` instead of `textBox.Text` and finally changing up the error messages so that they indicate which block they come from:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Test().button1_Click(null, null);
    }

    int rc;
    double centro, centro1;
    int r2, c2, rc2;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            string textBoxContents = "9";
            rc = Convert.ToInt16(textBoxContents);
            if (rc == 3 || rc == 5 || rc == 7 || rc == 9 || rc == 11)
            {
                centro = rc / 2;
                centro1 = Math.Round(centro, 0);
                int[,] dim = new int[rc, rc];
                int v = 1, r = 0, c, x = 0;
                c = Convert.ToInt16(centro1);
                //rc2 = rc;
                for (x = 0; x < (rc*rc); x++)
                {
                    if (dim[r, c] >= 1)
                    {
                        r = r2 + 2;
                        c = c2 - 1;
                        dim[r, c] = v;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dim[r, c] = v;
                    }
                    c++;
                    r--;
                    v++;
                    if (r < 0)
                    {
                        r = rc -1;
                    };
                    if (c > (rc-1))
                    {
                        c = 0;
                    };
                    r2 = r;
                    c2 = c;

                }
                string matrixString = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < dim.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dim.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        matrixString += dim[i, j].ToString();
                        matrixString += " ";
                    }

                    matrixString += Environment.NewLine;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(matrixString);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("***Else***   Verifica que:\n- Introduzcas   solo digitos.\n- Introduzcas solo numeros inpares\ndentro de las demensiones indicadas.\n- Solo introduzcas el numero de\nrenglones o columnas.");
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("***Exception***   Verifica que:\n- Introduzcas solo      digitos.\n- Introduzcas solo numeros inpares\ndentro de las demensiones indicadas.\n- Solo introduzcas el numero de\nrenglones o columnas.");
        }
    }

}
```

And see it running [here](http://ideone.com/9llD33).